# Scrapy xpath selectors not working when using chrome to define path

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to parse some pages from google. I saved the HTML from the response and I'm using google chrome to find the xpath selectors to the text I need:

The html returned is saved in this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/naV2N8u2

I'm going for this piece of text, which is directly under START houston:

`(20) · Coworking Space`

Chrome says the selector is:

`//*[@id="ires"]/ol/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/div[2]/text()`

But when I run the selector in scrapy I get an empty list

```
company_type_sel =  '//*[@id="ires"]/ol/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/div[2]/text()'
company_type_sel_response = Selector(response).xpath(company_type_sel).extract()
self.logger.info("Company Type responses: ")
self.logger.info(company_type_sel_response)
```

returns:

```
2018-02-15 11:10:31 [gspider] INFO: Company Type responses: 
2018-02-15 11:10:31 [gspider] INFO: []
```

Bonus question, how do I iterate over the list for `div[1]`, `div[2]`, etc?

Comment: First, tbody might be added by chrome for the sake of correctness, second your first xpath says `div[2]` but your code has `div/text()` only.

Comment: That was a copy error, I've corrected the code and I also tried running it without the `/tbody` but had no success

Comment: Try `//div[.="START houston"]/following-sibling::div[1]`.

Comment: This does work! (with `/text()` at the end) I have two questions: Can you explain why this works and also is there a generalizable xpath where I don't need to know the company name to find that text?

Comment: Unfortunately your html sample is big and it's not easy to see the structure, try `//*[@id="ires"]//div[@role="heading"]/following-sibling::div[1]/text()` or  `//*[@id="ires"]/descending::div[@role="heading"]/following-sibling::div[1]/text()`